# Como validar si hay un registro existente en una lista antes de ser insertado en java

Tags: java, arraylist

tengo un problema espero y me puedan ayudar, lo que pasa es que tengo una lista que extraigo de la base de datos, y lo que quiero es mas que nada validar antes de insertar, que si un registro existe en la lista que no lo inserte. Este es mi método de insertar:

```
public void insertSale() {

        origin_adm = Session.getOriginAdmActiva();
        cve_usr = Session.getUserCve();

        tipoVenta.setOrigin_adm(Integer.parseInt(origin_adm));
        tipoVenta.setUsr_cve(cve_usr);

        if (tipoVenta.getCve_type_of_sale() == null) {
            tipoVenta.setCve_type_of_sale(0);
        }
        //System.out.println("Descripcion..." + tipoVenta.getDesc_type_of_sale());
        if (tipoVenta.getDesc_type_of_sale() == null || tipoVenta.getDesc_type_of_sale().equals("")) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error: ", "Campo Requerido."));
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("alertaDistribucion");
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("ocultaMsj(3000)");

        }

        else {
            int ultimoRegistro = dao.saveTypeSale(tipoVenta);
            if (tipoVenta.getCve_type_of_sale() == 0) {

                System.out.println("Entro insert...");
                TipoVentaDTO tipoVentaDTO = new TipoVentaDTO();
                tipoVentaDTO.setOrigin_adm(tipoVenta.getOrigin_adm());
                tipoVentaDTO.setCve_type_of_sale(ultimoRegistro);
                tipoVentaDTO.setDesc_type_of_sale(tipoVenta.getDesc_type_of_sale());
                tipoVentaDTO.setUsr_cve(tipoVenta.getUsr_cve());

                listTipoVentas.add(tipoVentaDTO);
                listTipoVentasFiltradas.add(tipoVentaDTO);

                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Exito: ", "Venta insertada exitosamente."));
                RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("alertaDistribucion");
                RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("ocultaMsj(3000)");

            } else {
                System.out.println("Entro update...");
                for (int i = 0; i < listTipoVentas.size(); i++) {
                    if (listTipoVentas.get(i).getCve_type_of_sale() == tipoVenta.getCve_type_of_sale()) {
                        listTipoVentas.get(i).setDesc_type_of_sale(tipoVenta.getDesc_type_of_sale());
                    }

                }
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Exito: ", "venta actualizada exitosamente."));
                RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("alertaDistribucion");
                RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("ocultaMsj(3000)");

            }
            reset();
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("cancelar()");

        }

    }
```

No tengo idea de como empezar esa validación, espero y me puedan ayudar con este problema, quedo al pendiente, saludos cordiales y si hace falta algún otro dato, con gusto lo pongo.

Comment: de que lista hablas? porque no solo la recorres y te fijas si esta lo que vas a agregar?

Comment: Eso si me queda claro lo de recorrer la lista y perdon por no especificar cual lista, la lista se llama listTipoVentas y se encuentra dentro del else, el problema es que no sé exactamente donde poner el for para hacer el recorrido ya que en el primer else es cuando inserto

Comment: Toda validacion se debe hacer antes de todo. O sea, deberias tener u otro metodo que valide, o validar al principio.

Comment: Claro que si, por eso estoy intentando meter otra validacion mediante un for que haga el recorrido antes del primer else de mi codigo y de ahi mismo hacer la validación de que si ya esta en la lista no lo inserte

Comment: No comprendo tu problema. Y cual es el problema de que esa validacion se haga al principio de todo?

Answer (score 1):

Para fijarse si el array contiene un valor antes de agregarlo podes hacer esto

```
if (listTipoVentas.contains(valor_a_buscar)) {
    System.out.println("Se encontro el valor, no agregar");
} else {
    System.out.println("El valor no esta en la lista");
}
```

Podes leer un poco mas sobre como funciona contains en este [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29)

El problema por lo que no entra nunca a tu else es por esta linea

```
 if (tipoVenta.getCve_type_of_sale() == null) {
            tipoVenta.setCve_type_of_sale(0);
        }
```

Cada vez que llamas a tu metodo insertSale, seteas ese valor en 0 y luego lo comparas si es 0 aca

```
if (tipoVenta.getCve_type_of_sale() == 0) {...
```

Al ser 0 siempre va a entrar a llenar la lista pero nunca al else para usar el contains, te sugiero que chequees esa parte de la logica.

Comment: Hola buen dia, lo que quiero mas que nada es que cuando inserte mediante un input no lo inserte si ese mismo ya existe en la lista, lo que no se bien es donde poner un for para hacer el recorrido en la lista y compararlo con el objeto tipoVenta.getDesc_type_of_sale() en el primer else lo que lleva a dentro es cuando ya hará la inserción.

Comment: con contains no te hace falta un for, por que la lista ya esta llena, lo que hace es chequear si los elementos que estan en el array contienen el input que le pasas

Comment: Ya lo hice asi como el ejm en base a mi codigo pero no entra a esa condicion, no sé en que estoy haciendo :(

Comment: if (listTipoVentas.contains(tipoVenta.getDesc_type_of_sale())) {
            System.out.println("Se encontro el valor, no agregar");
        }

Comment: Si no entra es por que if (tipoVenta.getCve_type_of_sale() == 0) { es  0 siempre

Comment: ahi te modifique la respuesta

Comment: Si funciona todo bien asi como lo puse al principio, en este validador if (tipoVenta.getCve_type_of_sale() == 0)<-- lo que haga es que desde la bd si encuentra 0 va a insertar un registro y en el else va actualizar haciendo un recorrido y ver cual clave es el que se modificó, ya como tal el relajo viene desde una funcion en bd :)

Answer (score 0):

pues asi es como quedó mi solución:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < listTipoVentas.size(); i++) {
        if (listTipoVentas.get(i).getDesc_type_of_sale().equals(tipoVenta.getDesc_type_of_sale())) {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Error: ", "Valor insertado ya se encuentra."));
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("alertaDistribucion");
            RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("ocultaMsj(3000)");
            return;
        }

    }
```

Espero que a alguien le funcione, saludos chicos.

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo que en vez de traerte toda una consulta llena de registros, hagas una consulta con un procedimiento almacenado en el que le mandes el valor que necesitas que no se repita, puede ser un select a la tabla y que te devuelva un objeto. si el objeto viene vacío significa que no existe un registro con ese valor por lo tanto se puede registrar el producto, si el objeto viene con algo significa que ya existe.

O bien en tu base de datos puedes agregar una unique key al campo que necesitas que no se repita, aunque no lo recomiendo mucho ya que debes handlear la excepción en tu aplicación y aparte puede que te moleste esa unique key mas adelante si necesitas escalar tu base de datos